# Prevent scrolling up beyond a certain point in a sencha touch panel?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

Is there a way I can prevent scrolling up beyond a certain point in sencha touch? I have a panel that overflows vertically, but I don't want the user to be able to pull the content down (scroll up) to put vertical whitespace between the docked titlebar and the first bit of content.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just remove the padding/margin on the panel that is scrolling so there is no whitespace?

Comment: You can still scroll up, and there is no padding or margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would do is add a listener to the scroller of the panel. The scroller can be referenced by the scroller property of the panel.

Something like this. You'd have to play with it a bit but I think this should work. Code is untested.

```
  panel.scroller.addListener({
    'offsetchange': function (draggable, offset) {
        if (offset.y == 0) {
            panel.scroller.scrollTo({
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Changing the check from "offset.y == 0" to "offset.y > 0" made this work for me.